# Ограничить поле ввода RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

Есть ли возможность ограничить поле ввода в RichTextBox нижней границей? Т.е., если RichTextBox будет заполнен, должно быть невозможно добавить ещё текста/изображения/чего угодно. Свойство MaxLength не подойдёт, т.к. текст может (при высоком кегле) заполнить весь RichTextBox одним словом, а может и парой абзацев.
Может получится отследить момент до появления скролбара? Какое-нибудь событие перед Resize? Создать другой RichTextBox с такими же размерами, но невидимый, и, отслеживая запись в первом, сперва записывать во второй, и там уже проверять событие Resize - если сработало, то не записывать в первый? Но это будет уродливый костыль...

Comment: Если не секрет, а в чём прикол? Зачем именно такое ограничение?

Comment: Нет, такой возможности нет. И текст можно вставлять и из буфера обмена и в середину документа писать, куда угодно. К тому же у меня может быть 4k монитор, где места больше, при переносе приложения на обычный монитор, то что было введено ранее потеряется? Или как вы эту кучу проблем собрались решать?

Comment: @Виктор у меня есть panel - в нём richTextBox, я хотел динамически создавать новые richTextBox фиксированного размера, когда заполняются предыдущие - сделать что-то вроде страниц в текстовом редакторе

Comment: @aepot И правда, проблем не мало, спасибо. Мне это нужно было, чтобы организовать правильную печать документа - постранично. Тогда вернусь к своей первоначальной задумке - все в одном richTextBox, создам изображение из его содержимого и обрежу в конце по фиксированному размеру на несколько страниц

Answer (score 0):

Вот кусок кода с моей программы. Под себя переделай.

```
 if (textBoxInputIP.Text.Length > 15) // если длина текста больше 15 символов
            {
                textBoxInputIP.Text = textBoxInputIP.Text.Remove(textBoxInputIP.Text.Length - 1); //удаляем всё время 16 символ
                textBoxInputIP.SelectionStart = textBoxInputIP.Text.Length; //курсор к концу
            }
```

Comment: Length здесь - количество элементов из Text, т.е. количество букв - char. Я же описал, что richTextBox не должно волновать содержание - если не помещается содержимое, оно не должно добавляться

Comment: И выглядит это как появление и пропадаение символа на экране

Comment: @aepot ты прав, но это происходит моментально (невидно)

Comment: Если речь про обычный текстбокс, то ему можно вообще задать максимальную длину текста в свойствах. Если про рич, то эта операция очень медленная, так как на каждый тык заставляет его рендерить текст полностью заново при обращении к Text. А при переприсваивании пропадет все форматирование.

Comment: @aepot Не знал, спасибо!